# Cannot modify expression because it is not a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying to get an UserControl (which has a grid on it) on a Windows Form to resize.
The below code is what I have in the Form.  The behavior I'm getting is that the control is resized when I make it big.  But it does not shrink.  What am I doing wrong (or) What am I missing?

```
private void AdjustGrid()
{
    ZoomControl.Location = new Point(5, 5);
    ZoomControl.Size = new Size(this.Width - 15, this.Height - 75);
}

void zoomform_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdjustGrid();
}
```

Now the user control has the following code:

```
//Resize the grid that the UserControl has on it
private void NameValuePropertyBag_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdNameValueProperties.Location = new Point(4,4);
    grdNameValueProperties.Size = new Size(this.Width - 8, this.Height - 8);
}
```

<strike>I tried</strike>

```
grdNameValueProperties.Size.Width = this.Width - 8;
grdNameValueProperties.Size.Height = this.Height -8;
```

It gives me "Cannot modify expression because it is not a variable" error...  What am I missing?

Additional Info:

I'm using SetParent() Windows call to move/zoom an UserControl to another Form (ZoomForm). 

<strike>Anchor doesn't seem to work for controls moved with SetParent()... More precisely, it may be working but I have repainting problems.</strike>

I got Anchor/Dock pair to working without repaint issues [I removed the resize event wireup and adjusted Dock to Fill]

The ZoomForm initally has no controls.  The Usercontrol is added to the ParentForm dynamically.

Currently, I'm able to make the zoom form bigger <strike>with the above code</strike> but not smaller.

Comment: Why don't you just use the anchor properties instead of code to resize?

Comment: @recursive: I'm using SetParent() Windows call to move/zoom an UserControl to another Form (ZoomForm). Anchor doesn't seem to work for controls moved with SetParent()...  More precisely, it may be working but I have repainting problems

Answer (score 7):

```
grdNameValueProperties.Size.Width = this.Width - 8;
grdNameValueProperties.Size.Height = this.Height - 8;
```

That code gives the error because `Size` is a value type, not a reference type. Reading [this](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html) may help explain the difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 4):

As recursive commented, you should just use the Anchor property.

The error occurse because the Size property exposes a struct and not a reference type. The Size property returns a copy of the size object of the control. Writing to the properties Width and Hight of this copy makes no sense because it is just a temporary copy and not backed by memory anywhere.

Comment: @danbruc:  It's not the first time I've been SOOO dumb.  Thanks anyway for the refresher :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly change the `Size.Width` property on a UserControl, because the `Size` property is a value type, so changing its width would essentially be overwriting the entire `Size` property. Instead, controls in WinForms provide their own Width and Height properties, so this code should work:

```
grdNameValueProperties.Width = this.Width - 8;
grdNameValueProperties.Height = this.Height - 8;
```

Having said that, I agree with @recursive's comment that you should probably just use the UserControl's `Anchor` property to make it "automatically" resize.

Comment: @Matt:  Thanks... I did get rid of new Size() assignments.  I still have the same problem:  I can make the form bigger but not smaller :(

Comment: Which Resize event are you catching? The event on a control on which the UserControl sits? Can you catch the form's Resize event instead?

Answer (score 1):

*Currently, I'm able to make the zoom form bigger with the above code but not smaller.*

Some controls have a MinSize (or similar) property on them.  Do you have any of those set such that you can't resize smaller?

Comment: @JP: Checked that... Doesn't seem to be the issue... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first portion -

First off, I'd recommend using the Anchor property on UserControl instead of trying to size this yourself.  It works very simply, and very reliably, for handling window resizing.

If you want to do this, you should probably look at chaining off this.ClientSize instead of this.Height and this.Width.  You're probably setting your control too large, and that's unachoring the panel or other thing you're sitting on, which causes all sorts of issues.

The second part is due to the fact that gridNameValue Properties.Size.Width is a member of a struct.

When you call gridNameValueProperties.Size, you're returning a Size struct, then trying to set the Width on the returned struct (not the original).  This is why you need to set the entire Size valuetype in one shot.  Creating a new Size() and setting it to gridNameValueProperties.Size is the only way to make that work.

Comment: @Reed: The size does change.  UserControl and its child controls do become bigger if I resize the form (make it bigger, that is).  The form wouldn't let me make it smaller though.

Comment: Do you have anything else on your form other than the UserControl?  If there is another container in the form that the user control is in, and you set the user control "too large" for hte client area, I've seen this behavior.  That's why I suggested changing to ClientSize.