# Does a C# indexer return a variable or value?

Tags: c#

Mutable structs are error-prone; `dictionary[0].Inflate(1,1)` doesn't behave the same as `array[0].Inflate(1,1)` would when `T` is a Rectangle (since `array[0]` is a *variable*, whereas `dictionary[0]` is a *value*).

If I make a custom indexer for `SomeClass`:

```
public T this[int x, int y] { get { return arr[y*100+x]; } }
```

Is `someclass[x,y]` a *variable* or *value* or neither? Presuming `T` is, of course, a `struct`.

Comment: Do you mean Value Type and Reference Type, not value and variable?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up *variable* and *reference type*

Comment: @psubsee2003 I believe *value* and *variable* are the correct terminology for when T is a struct.

Comment: @Mr.Smith I don't think so.  A struct is always a Value Type.  It can never be anything different.  A variable is not a type at all.

Comment: @Mr.Smith From MSDN: Variables represent storage locations. Every variable has a type that determines what values can be stored in the variable.

Comment: @psubsee2003 See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4727371/1362135

Comment: @Mr.Smith ok, makes sense, it was a choice of terminology that I was not familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An indexer access expression is initially classified as an "indexer access". From section 7.6.6.2 of the C# 4 spec:

> The result of processing the indexer access is an expression classified as an indexer access

And then from section 7.1:

> A property access or indexer access is always reclassified as a value by performing an invocation of the *get-accessor* or *set-accessor*.

So basically you can think of it as being classified as a value.

However, an *array* access is classified as a variable expression. From section 7.6.6.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> The result of evaluating an array access is a variable of the element type of the array [...]

That's why this is fine:

```
string[] x = { "", "", "" };
SomeMethodWithRef(ref x[0]);
```

But this isn't:

```
List<string> x = new List<string> { "", "", "" };
SomeMethodWitHRef(ref x[0]);
```

Comment: Just to be absolutely certain I'm reading this right, does that imply my indexer is returning a *copy* of the struct `T`?

Comment: @Mr.Smith: Yes, in exactly the same way as a simple assignment would copy the value.