# Can a Swift subscript return a variable?

Tags: swift

In C#, the only indexer that actually returns a *variable*<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20920021/1362135),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4727371/1362135)</sup> are array indexers.

```cs
void Make42(ref int x) {x=42;}
void SetArray(int[] array){
    Make42(ref array[0]);} //works as intended; array[0] becomes 42
void SetList(List<int> list){
    Make42(ref list[0]);} //does not work as intended, list[0] stays 0
```

In the example above, `array[0]` is a variable, but `list[0]` is not. This is the culprit behind many developers, writing high-performance libraries, being forced to write their own List implementations (that, unlike the built-in [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), expose the underlying array) to get *benchmark worthy* performance out of the language.

In Swift, `ref` is called `inout` and `indexer` seems to be called `subscript`. I'm wondering if there's any mechanisms in Swift's [`subscript`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Subscripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH16-XID_393) to explicitly return a *variable* rather than a *value* (a *value* can be a value-type or reference-type).

Comment: Can you name any good reason why the code you hinted at should be something one might need?

Comment: @Mithrandir, languages exist to satisfy much more than any specific person's needs. Subscript references could be about just as useful as variable references.

Answer (score 2):

If I may bring in C++ parlance, you'd be looking to return a *reference* to a value. I'm using the term here because it's generally better understood by the programming crowd.

The reason C# limits it to just arrays is that returning arbitrary references [may compromise the language's safety guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339602/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-the-return-of-references) if not done properly.

There appears to be no syntax to return a reference in Swift. Since returning references is hard to verify, and since Swift is rather new and since it aims at being a safe language, it is understandable that Apple didn't go this way.

If you get to a level where you need this kind of performance, you may want to consider C++, in which you can sacrifice almost all the safety you want to get performance.